# How to create custom function/formatter nelmio/alice v.3?

Tags: symfony4, nelmio-alice

I'm new to symfony 4 and tried to write my own function for yml nelmio/alice, but after I ran `bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load` , I got this error:

> In DeepCopy.php line 177:
>
> The class "ReflectionClass" is not cloneable.

Here is my fixtures.yml file:

```
App\Entity\Post:
post_{1..10}:
    title: <customFunction()>
```

Here is my AppFixture.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Nelmio\Alice\Loader\NativeLoader;



class AppFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $loader = new NativeLoader();

        $objectSet = $loader->loadFile(__DIR__.'/Fixtures.yml',
            [
                'providers' => [$this]
            ]
        )->getObjects();

        foreach($objectSet as $object) {
            $manager->persist($object);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function customFunction() {

        // Some Calculations

        return 'Yep! I have got my bonus';
    }

}
```

Comment: The "not clonable" comes from the fact that at some point, the library tries to deep clone your provider instance (`this`) but the class holds a reference to the manager (I had a similar issue but my _class_ held a reference to the application container) causes this error to be raised. I moved the code into an isolated provider class which solved the problem.

Comment: That's the great trick but in my case the problem was I mixed the previous version way of defining a formatter with the last version.

Comment: I am now stuck on another issue, maybe you could help me ? In that case please see: [this post _alice-fixtures-persist-and-reference_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648923/alice-fixtures-persist-and-reference-a-first-set-of-entities-objects) Thank you for your time.

Comment: Because that is an another topic, I posted an answer there. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After investigating about nelmio/alice new version, I found the solution:

We should first create a provider which is a class that contains our new custom functions. Second, extend the `NativeLoader` class to register our new provider. Third, use our new NativeLoader (Here is CustomNativeLoader) which allows us to use our new formatters.

Here is the provider in CustomFixtureProvider.php:

```
<?php


namespace App\DataFixtures;
use Faker\Factory;

class CustomFixtureProvider
{
    public function title()
    {
        $faker = Factory::create();

        $title = $faker->text($faker->numberBetween(20,100));

        return $title;

    }
}
```

As a side note, the `title` function generates some dummy titles for your articles or posts or etc. which have dynamic length between 20..100 character. This function use Faker Alice built-in formatters.

Here is CustomNativeLoader.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use Nelmio\Alice\Faker\Provider\AliceProvider;
use Nelmio\Alice\Loader\NativeLoader;
use Faker\Factory as FakerGeneratorFactory;
use Faker\Generator as FakerGenerator;

class CustomNativeLoader extends NativeLoader
{
    protected function createFakerGenerator(): FakerGenerator
    {
        $generator = FakerGeneratorFactory::create(parent::LOCALE);
        $generator->addProvider(new AliceProvider());
        $generator->addProvider(new CustomFixtureProvider());
        $generator->seed($this->getSeed());

        return $generator;
    }
}
```

Here is LoadFixture.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\DataFixtures\CustomNativeLoader;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class LoadFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $loader = new CustomNativeLoader();

        $objectSet = $loader->loadFile(__DIR__ . '/fixtures.yml')->getObjects();
        foreach($objectSet as $object) {
            $manager->persist($object);
        }
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

And finally an example for using our new `title` formatter:

```
App\Entity\Post:
    post_{1..10}:
        title: <title()>
```

I know this is a long way for writing a small function but according to my investigation, it's a standard way for extending the formatters in new version.

Comment: you could simplify `createFakerGenerator ` by calling the parent one and just append the provider to it, but otherwise that's the way to go

Comment: Would you please provide me an example. Then I can improve the answer

Comment: Looks like it is a bit out dated, I get this error: PHP TypeError:  Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Loader\SymfonyFixturesLoader::addFixture() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface, instance of AppBundle\DataFixtures\CustomFixtureProvider given

Comment: This is especially helpful for those of us NOT using symfony - but still needing a way to add new providers to Alice + Faker. The documentation on the readme in Alice: "Then you can add it to the Faker Generator used by Alice by either overriding the NativeLoader::createFakerGenerator() method." left me a bit confused. Either, .... or? What? But, seeing this, it's clear that yes, all you need to do is extend the Loader, and override the FakerGenerator method.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this simple way:

1.Create your own provider (for example, in /src/DataFixtures/Faker/CustomProvider.php):

```
 <?php    
    namespace App\DataFixtures\Faker;


    class CustomProvider
    {
        public static function customFunction()
        {
            // Some Calculations
            return 'Yep! I have got my bonus';
        }
    }
```

2.Register provider in config/services.yaml:

```
App\DataFixtures\Faker\CustomProvider:
    tags: [ { name: nelmio_alice.faker.provider } ]
```

That's it.

P.S. You can check for more details here: https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle/blob/master/doc/faker-providers.md

Comment: in any case, this still needs to be loaded properly (passing the Faker\Generator), otherwise the new Faker provider won't be picked up. For example:
`return (new NativeLoader($this->getService(Faker\Generator::class)))->loadFiles($files)->getObjects();`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible also like ( addition to the solution bellow https://stackoverflow.com/a/54116196/261058 ):

###### EntityServiceProvider.php

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Infrastructure\FixtureProvider;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Exception;
use Faker\Generator;
use Faker\Provider\Base;

class EntityServiceProvider extends Base
{
    public function __construct(Generator $generator, private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->unique(true);
        parent::__construct($generator);
    }

    /**
     * @template T of object
     * @param class-string<T> $class
     * @return T
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function entityReference(string $class, string $columnName, string|int|bool $columnValue)
    {
        if (!class_exists($class)) {
            throw new Exception(sprintf('Class "%s" does not exist or it isn\'t loaded', $class));
        }
        $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository($class);
        $foundEntity = $repository->findOneBy([$columnName => $columnValue]);

        if (!$foundEntity instanceof $class) {
            throw new Exception(sprintf('Entity "%s" with given criteria wasn\'t found', $class));
        }
        return $foundEntity;
    }
}
```

###### Service definition: service.yaml

```yaml
App\Infrastructure\FixtureProvider\EntityServiceProvider:
    tags:
        - { name: 'nelmio_alice.faker.provider' }
```

###### Usage in fixtures yaml

```yaml
App\Domain\Location\Address:
    address0:
        id: '<numberBetween(3000,99999)>'
        country: '<entityReference(App\Domain\Location\Country, code, DE)>'
```

###### loading objects from fixture yaml

```php
protected function loadObjectsFromFixtures(array $files): array
    {
        return (new NativeLoader($this->getService(Faker\Generator::class)))->loadFiles($files)->getObjects();
    }
```